# how to use Alfresco Sharepoint protocol in my java web application

Tags: java, sharepoint, web-applications, alfresco

I have an existing Java web application with document and spreadsheet files in Microsoft Office format.
I want to provide Sharepoint-like edit online functionality to allow user to edit files in Word and Excel and save them to the server.

I try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160494/how-to-use-alfresco-edit-online-functionality-from-spring-mvc-application) with the edit link generated from Alfresco but it only works in IE.
So do I have to use some cross-browser library for ActiveXObject support?
Or is there any easy way to embed the document edit link from Alfresco into my web application?

And for the document to be accessible by the protocol:
Do I have to use Alfresco services to upload my documents?
Or can I embed Alfresco server or Alfresco's VTI Jetty server into my application to serve my documents?

---

**EDIT**

So there is not any cross-browser ActiveX
After read Alfresco's [action.js](http://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/slingshot/source/web/components/documentlibrary/actions.js), I find out that there is something called Sharepoint plugin.
I have no problem generating the edit link now

---

**EDIT 2**

Microsoft Office works fine with normal WebDAV server, so there is no need for embedding Alfresco in my web application

Comment: What version of Alfresco are you trying with? 4.0 should work fine for Edit Online with most browsers on Windows and OSX, provided that Microsoft Office is installed on the client machine

Comment: I know that Alfresco can do that. I want to integrate that functionality in my own existing web application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no need for any special code within the browser. As Gagravarr said, the links should work fine when Office is installed on the client.

Although it can be done, most likely you do not want to embed an Alfresco repository (with or without Jetty) within your application and use its CMIS and/or RESTful HTTP interfaces to work on content. Embedding a repository means introducing various dependencies. I see no reasoning in your scenario.

Comment: I have no problem using online edit in Alfresco, I just want the online edit link to appear in my web application. The "special code" is needed if I have to use Javascript to roll my own implementation.
And if I can embed that link in my application, can you tell me how :( I can't find it in any documentation.

Comment: And I want to embed Alfresco/VTI server in my application because I want to use them to serve my existing files instead of migrating all of them to alfresco.

Comment: If it is just the server part of the sharepoint protocol you are after, you might want to checkout out alfresco source code in root/modules/sharepoint. This code is based on Alfresco foundation classes so you'll either have to replace the backing code by your own implemention or you'll have to embed a full Alfresco repository. In the latter case this implies migrating your content into alfresco and various dependencies.

Comment: The client-side is ok now. I'm looking at the server part. Thank for your answer.

Comment: Hey, any chance could you share how you solved this? I'm trying to do pretty much the same thing now.